# Firestore database in React

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried and tried to get this to work, but everything throws one error or another. This is what I have now, written in the same syntax as latest Firebase documentation.

firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "blurred-out",
  authDomain: "blurred-out",
  projectId: "blurred-out",
  storageBucket: "blurred-out",
  messagingSenderId: "blurred-out",
  appId: "blurred-out"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
 
export default db;
```

App.js:

```
import db from "./firebase";
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('collectionName').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    );
  }, []);
```

But it still throws this error:

> *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_["default"].collection is not a function. (In '*firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_["default"].collection("collectionName")', '*firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_["default"].collection' is undefined)

Comment: It could help to show the code that return this error. I don't see `collection()` called here, so the error might come from another part of your applciation.

Comment: @raaaahman sorry i missed that! i've updated my post to include the call. thank you for taking a look!

Comment: v8 code won't work with v9 firebase

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'apiKey',
  authDomain: 'authDomain',
  projectId: 'projectId',
  storageBucket: 'storageBucket',
  messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId',
  appId: 'appId'
}

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = getFirestore(app)

export const save = async (obj) => {
  const coll = collection(db, 'collectionName')
  const docRef = doc(coll, 'docName')
  await setDoc(docRef, obj)
}
```

Don't forget to install firebase:

```
npm i firebase
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much! and i also had to update my call like this:

  `const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const coll = collection(db, "posts");
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(coll, (snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);`

Comment: Nice. Looks good, try to separate the logic from the component.